# What are the different CD's & DVD's for?

Tags: debian, system-installation

I'm planning to install Debian on my home server. It will be running some services like Teamspeak 3, gaming servers, Samba, etc... No business services like DHCP, DNS, ... needed.

So as this is my first time installing Debian I found this site where you can download dvd's and cd's for installation (amd64):
https://www.debian.org/CD/http-ftp/

Now I see there are a whole bunch of different CD's and DVD's. **I know that only the first DVD / CD is required for basic / core installation and that the others contain additional optional features.**

**What I am searching for now is something like a list, which DVD / CD contains what.** I could not find anything on this topic in the internet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at [Debian CD FAQ](https://www.debian.org/CD/faq/#which-cd):

> The packages are sorted by popularity: The first CD/DVD contains
>   the installation system and the most popular packages. The second
>   one contains slightly less popular ones, the third one even less
>   popular ones, etc.  You will probably only need the first DVD (or
>   the first two CDs) unless you have very special requirements.
>   (And in case you happen to need a package later on which is not
>   on one of the CDs/DVDs you downloaded, you can always install that
>   package directly from the Internet.)

The same FAQ also has a link to [cdimage.debian.org](http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/), where you can find *the lists* you asked for.

Regarding popularity, [popcon](http://popcon.debian.org/stable/index.html) is probably a good place to look.